# Can't seem to figure out how to start a service in Android

Tags: java, android

So, I'm not exactly new to Java, or Android, but I still have some issues sometimes. I'm currently working on an app that streams Shoutcast and Icecast stations, and I want to put the MediaPlayer in a service (so it's not killed)

Well...I can't seem to figure out how to start a [service](https://github.com/iPonyRadio/iPonyRadio-Android/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/iponyradio/android/BackgroundService.java) from [this Activity](https://github.com/iPonyRadio/iPonyRadio-Android/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/iponyradio/android/PlayerActivity.java) which crashes right on launch from [this Activity](https://github.com/iPonyRadio/iPonyRadio-Android/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/iponyradio/android/SingleStationActivity.java)

I honestly can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've looked at the Android Developer Documentation and Guide, as well as a couple tutorials, and I get nothing. No progress.

Anyone see anything? (And before anyone picks through the code, yes I do plan on fixing the way I parse twice)

Comment: check if your service is not destroyed after onHandleIntent()

Answer (score 0):

An `IntentService` is by design a work queue. That means you start it, `onHandleIntent()` runs repeatedly until the queue is empty, then it is destroyed. Each "start" adds one item to the intent service's work queue.

You'll want to use a regular service, and start a thread therein to host whatever long-running task you have. The topic of services is much too large to cover here, but you'll want to consider [`startForeground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) to keep your service running. The simple fact that it's a service does nothing to guarantee that it won't be destroyed.

Comment: That still doesn't explain the App Crash, but thank yiou

Comment: you didn't post what the crash was, which makes it sort of hard.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't pull an adb logcat, so that is why I haven't solved it myslf. There is an apk [here](https://github.com/iPonyRadio/iPonyRadio-Android/blob/master/mobile/mobile-release.apk)

Comment: If I can debug it and get the logcat by installing the APK and running, why can't you?

Comment: because I-wow I feel dumb I know that there are on device logcat applications.

Comment: how about running your app on a device where you can use ADB?